# How To Create A Throbbing Effect In After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I've searched here and elsewhere for an answer but I can't find exactly what I am looking for. I am working on a video ad in After Affects and I have an image that I want to make throb, kind of like a heartbeat. Not necessarily looking for a double throb like a heart, just a throb in general. Would appreciate some advice if anyone has created this effect before. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post an example of the kind of effect you mean - even if you don't know how to make it?

Comment: I just figured out how to do this. NVM.